# How to use zfill as increment counter in python?

Tags: python, count

I want to start count as 00000_keypoints, 00001_keypoints....

```
c = 0
{my code}
c += 1
```

How can i do using zfill? As zfill works only on string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to work it out using zfill. Thanks.

```
f"{str(c).zfill(5)}_keypoints"
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need zfill:

```
s = f"{c:05d}_keypoints"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either f-string (I'd recommend) or `zfill`

```
for i in range(n):
    name1 = f"{i:05d}_keypoints"
    name2 = "{}_keypoints".format(str(i).zfill(5))
    print(name1, name2)
    # your code here
```